# How to select first child div using class in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I am having sidebar boxes and I want to change content of single box on the click event.

Here is my code :

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <div class="box">    //box 1 
        <div class="box-t">      
            <div class="box-b">
                <div class="">
                    <h2>This is sample box 1</h2>
                    <p style="text-align: left;">Please give us a shout at 
                        <a href="mailto:concierge@example.com">concierge@example.com</a>.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">    //box 2 
        <div class="box-t">      
            <div class="box-b">
                <div class="">
                    <h2>This is sample box 2</h2>
                    <p style="text-align: left;">Please give us a shout at 
                        <a href="mailto:concierge@example.com">concierge@example.com</a>.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> //sidebar div close
```

Above code is get generated dynamically and I want change the content of first box on a click of one button.

So to access first child div from sidebar, I have made a use of :

```
$('div.sidebar > : first-child').html('<div>hiiiiiiii</div>');
```

and also I have tried  :

```
$('div.sidebar > : first-child').replaceWith('hiiiiiiii');
```

But both above attempts are not changing any data.

What is missing or is there any other way to change the content from of single div from multiple divs whose having same class ?

Comment: Use this $('div.sidebar > :first-child')

Comment: Adding to @Jérôme comment http://jsfiddle.net/D9z9q/

Answer (score 4):

You do **not** need parent `>` child here also you must **not** have space between `:` and `first-child`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k84LG/)**

```
$('div.sidebar :first-child').html('<div>hiiiiiiii</div>');
```

> [**:first-child**](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) Selects all elements that are the first child of their
>   parent.

If you just want first element then go for `:first`

> [**:first**](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) Selects the first matched element.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k84LG/2/)**

```
$('div.sidebar :first').html('<div>hiiiiiiii</div>');
```

Comment: Very important distinction here between `:first-child` and `:first` which makes this the most appropriate answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try  this:

```
$('div.sidebar').first().html('<div>hiiiiiiii</div>');
```

OR

```
$('div.sidebar').eq(1).html('<div>hiiiiiiii</div>');
```

OR

```
$('div.sidebar')[0].html('<div>hiiiiiiii</div>');
```

Comment: Sorry, but the last one wont work, it returns an plain Object, and has no `.html function`! `$("div")[0].innerHTML = "..."`

Comment: I did not try the last one but you can try like this: $($('div.sidebar')[0]).html('<div>hiiiiiiii</div>');

Answer (score 2):

you need to use `:first`. it will select only the first child of div with class sidebar:

```
$("div.sidebar :first").html('<div>hiiiiiiii</div>');
```

[**Here is DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/G6y5z/1/)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the space between `:` and `first-child`. When you're using space, the selector will try to match a descendant `:` of `div.sidebar` which will result in this syntax error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: div.sidebar > : first-child
```

So you need to remove the space:

```
$('div.sidebar > :first-child').html('<div>hiiiiiiii</div>');
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9U2QW/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.sidebar : first-child').html('<div>hi with just 1 i </div>');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('div.sidebar :first-child').html('hiiiiii');
```

[Refer here](https://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/)

No space needed between : and first